# Is my DDE system solvable?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve a system of two differential delayed equations, but I have some problems. I think that second equation is not mathematicaly correct  because of position of time derivatives. Can you confirm that?

$\qquad \dfrac{dx}{dt}=b \sin(2 \omega \pi t) + c \cos(2 \omega \pi t)  + y(t-\sigma) +dS$

$\qquad \dfrac{dy}{dt}=\nu dt + dS(t)$

My opinion is that right side of second equation cannot be integrated because of the first term on the right side, that consists of $\nu dt \cdot dt$ is not a usual term in differential equations, so I am not sure it is possible to integrate that. Am I right?

Comment: Hummm... First ode does not depend on $y(t)$ and second ODE does not depend on $x(t)$.  So what is the problem? Solve the first ODE to find $x(t)$. Then integrate the second equation to find $y(t)$.

Comment: I made error, I corrected it, there is dependence between equations. Is second equation solvable for itself, because of position of dt?

Comment: I agree that these equations do not make sense.  Please post corrected equations in Mathematica format, or delete the question.    Thanks.

Comment: I corrected equation by my mistake but I am not sure what is corrected matemathicaly.

Comment: 1) Is that related to Mathematica? Maybe you meant to post on math.SE instead. 2) Your equation is a DDE iff it can be written in the form of a [DDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_differential_equation), which does not seem to be the case. It depends how you define $dt$ and $dS$...